# React native-How to return item from AsyncStorage to use outside of async function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm trying to use an item from AsyncStorage, stored as a variable created in an async function, however, when it is returned, it returns as undefined.

```
import React from 'react';
import {View,Text,TouchableOpacity,StyleSheet}from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
function App(){
  async function save() {
    let info = ['space']
    AsyncStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(info))
  }
  async function show1() {
    try {
      let show = await AsyncStorage.getItem('key');
      show = JSON.parse(show)
      console.log('item:', show)
      return show;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
  const read=(show)=> {
    console.log(show)
  }
  show1();
```

The function read is called by a button and logs 'undefined' instead of ['space'].In the async function it correctly logs show as ['space'], but doesn't seem to return it.
Is it possible to use an aysnc item outside of an async function or am i missing something.

Comment: missing await. try,  await AsyncStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(info))

Comment: @AswinC doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By defining

`const read=(show)=> {
    console.log(show)
  }`

you are declaring a function that takes a parameter, that will be referred as `show` in the scope of that function.

What you should be doing is:

```
const read = show1();
console.log(read);`
```

or

```
const read = () => {
 console.log(show1());
}
read();
```

What you should remember is that when you declare a variable in a function, it is not accessible outside the scope of this function.

So if you do:

```
function myAssign() {
let a = 10;
console.log(a) // 10
}
console.log(a) // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Using AsyncStorage directly is too complicated. Maybe you can consider using [react-native-easy-app](https://github.com/chende008/react-native-easy-app/blob/master/README.en-US.md). Through it, you can access AsyncStorage in the form of assignment and value, and it supports string, object and boolean data access, Sample project page [Storagecontroller.js](https://github.com/chende008/react-native-easy-app-sample/blob/master/src/Main/Home/storage/StorageController.js)

```
  import { XStorage } from 'react-native-easy-app';
  import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
  // or import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

   export const RNStorage = {
       token: undefined, 
       isShow: undefined, 
       userInfo: undefined
   };

  const initCallback = () => {

       // From now on, you can write or read the variables in RNStorage synchronously

       // equal to [console.log(await AsyncStorage.getItem('isShow'))]
       console.log(RNStorage.isShow); 

       // equal to [ await AsyncStorage.setItem('token',TOKEN1343DN23IDD3PJ2DBF3==') ]
       RNStorage.token = 'TOKEN1343DN23IDD3PJ2DBF3=='; 

       // equal to [ await AsyncStorage.setItem('userInfo',JSON.stringify({ name:'rufeng', age:30})) ]
       RNStorage.userInfo = {name: 'rufeng', age: 30}; 
  };

  XStorage.initStorage(RNStorage, AsyncStorage, initCallback);
```

Comment: I tried using react native easy app and found it pretty interesting, however when i try to add to an array(using push or splice) in RNStorage, that added element is not saved, can this be fixed.

Comment: @Jamazing ,The implementation of RNStorage is based on the setter and setter of js, so the setItem or getItem operation of AsyncStorage will be triggered only when the property of RNStorage is set or assigned. It is recommended that you can save the data in a temporary variable and assign it to the corresponding attribute of RNStorage after the modification is completed.

Comment: Using easy app i can no longer use useState, I get an invalid hook call error even though it follows hook rules, is there a fix?

Comment: @Jamazing I don't quite understand what you mean. If there is an error, please give an example. Is there no way to know your problem? What is certain is that easy-app can be used with react hooks. After RNStorage is initialized, you can use it as a memory variable anywhere.